# In what order should someone face when shaking the lulav?

Tags: halacha, minhag, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

When shaking the lulav and etrog in 6 directions, is there a proper order?

My ArtScroll (USA) siddur says to shake FRBLUD - forwards, right, backwards, left, up, down. In my shul, many people do LFRBUD.

Is there a standard/proper order?

If it matters, facing left in my shul is east, as Yerushalayim is to the south.